# How to define a unique object in a for loop in C++

Tags: c++

I have java/python experience and recently started working on a C++ project. I ran into this very generic problem and wasn't able to find any clear answer/explanation in StackOverflow. The concepts behind is probably very basic, but still most of the things I tried seems to fail this far, so I thought it is worth to post it here and learn the "proper C++ way".

I'm trying to create a vector of objects in a for loop. The code I have is something like below which works:

```
  int NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS = 6;
  std::vector<SomeObject> objects = std::vector<SomeObject>(NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS; i++) {
    std::string name = "Object" + std::to_string(i);
    test::SetObject(&objects[i], name.data());
  }
```

however if I try something like:

```
  std::vector<SomeObject> objects;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> object = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
    objects.push_back(*object.get());
    std::string name = "Object" + std::to_string(i);
    test::SetObject(&objects[i]);
  }
```

it doesn't work (ie below prints the same address):

```
for (SomeObject o : objects) {
  std::cout << "object address: " << &o << "\n";
}
```

I thought that's because the [docs of unique_ptr](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/memory/unique_ptr.html) says "The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when ... unique_ptr managing the object is destroyed". So I tried to preserve the unique_ptr by creating a vector of it, something like:

```
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>> objects;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> object = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
    objects.push_back(object);
    std::string name = "Object" + std::to_string(i);
    test::SetObject(&(*objects[i].get()));
  }
```

but instead of preserving the unique_ptr, this instead still destroys the object and warns me `call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>'`

I guess putting the unique_ptr to a vector is not enough to make C++ not destroy that unique_ptr, maybe I need to do something like std::move? I feel like something as basic as initialising a list of objects is probably done very frequently and should have a simpler way to it.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could elaborate how memory management works in C++ for practical purposes (eg. I know I could use new, but read that in most cases I should use make_unique instead to avoid leaking memory)

Comment: what is `test::SetObject(&objects[i]);` ?

Comment: You can't store `std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>` in a  `std::vector<SomeObject>`. 
As long as an object can be copied or moved you can use push_back(object), and there is no need for pointers (unique or otherwise)
Also have a look a this : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/intro-to-smart-pointers-move-semantics/

Comment: [this should clarify a lot](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it was some method that initialises the object by address

Comment: @PepijnKramer I see, thanks for the link! seems like if I want to store it in a vector I still need to do std::move :)

Comment: @MarekR thanks a lot, I just solved this with Jarod42's answer but I'm still watching the link you shared

Comment: Well not using std::move will copy the class (if it can be copied), if the class has a move constructor (can be default generated) then its moved. Move constructors are typically needed when a class holds resources. (Lookup RAII, its a much used concept in C++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> object = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
objects.push_back(*object.get());
```

can be simplified to

```
SomeObject object{};
objects.push_back(object);
```

or even

```
objects.emplace_back();
```

Your issue in 2nd/3rd snippet is that vector is resized, so inernal pointer and iterator are invalidated:

```
test::SetObject(&objects[i]); // dangling pointer after objects.push_back(*object.get());
```

[`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) might solve your issue:

```
std::vector<SomeObject> objects;
object.reserve(6);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    SomeObject object{};
    objects.push_back(object);
    std::string name = "Object" + std::to_string(i);
    test::SetObject(&objects[i]);
}
```

or use vector of (smart) pointer:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>> objects;
// object.reserve(6); // No longer needed
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    std::unique_ptr<SomeObject> object = std::make_unique<SomeObject>();
    objects.push_back(std::move(object));
    // or simply
    // objects.push_back(std::make_unique<SomeObject>());
    std::string name = "Object" + std::to_string(i);
    test::SetObject(objects[i].get());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not your other code that is flawed, it's the loop where you print the addresses to the objects:

```
for (SomeObject o : objects) {
  std::cout << "object address: " << &o << "\n";
}
```

Here a brand new `o` object will be created each iteration of the loop. But nothing stops the compiler to *reuse the same memory* for the object `o`.

If you want to get each "unique" object from the container, use references instead:

```
for (SomeObject const& o : objects) { ... }
```

Comment: oh that's a very good point, thank you!